# Why does an APK file size of 7.6 MB allocate 1.36 GB on an exFAT formatted external hard drive when reverse-engineered?

Tags: macos, apk, apktool, apfs, exfat

I have an apk file size of `7.6 MB`. When I reverse-engineer this `apk` file through [apktool](https://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/), which is a reverse engineering tool for `apk` files, it allocates `1.36 GB` on an `exFAT` formatted external hard drive. Actually when I extract this apk file on my local drive (`APFS` formatted Macintosh HD), it allocates `32.1 MB` which is fair. What could be the reason behind this odd situation?

**Client:**

OS: `macOS Catalina 10.15.2`

Process: A typical `Java` process that is executed through a `jar` file

Comment: exFAT doesn't have symlinks. APFS does. Maybe that's the reason.

Answer (score 2):

Check the Memory Allocation Size of the exFAT external HDD. exFAT has a much larger default memory allocation size, and if you went with the default it might me something like 1MB (like mentioned in [this post](https://sava.io/huge-file-size-apfs-exfat)). This means that all your files that have size < 1MB will actually have size on disk 1MB.

Having lots of files much smaller in size than the MAS would explain the enormous size difference.